# Required cordova.js file not found. Cordova plugins will not function! Capacitor: FATAL ERROR

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, capacitor

I updated my Ionic 2.5 App to Ionic 4.

The app was building on iOS as expected but when I ran it, it was throwing me this error: "Required cordova.js file not found. Cordova plugins will not function! Capacitor: FATAL ERROR".

I tried

- removing all Cordova plugins
- disabling angular buildOptimizer and optimization

Answer (score 0):

After some struggle I figured out that the "public" folder wasn't present in the Xcode project. According to [this](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0) article we must remove and re-add the public folder.

Apparently ionic builds the web and scripts into www folder and then copies them to iOS/App/App/public folder. Since the files weren't in that folder the app wasn't able to process those riles.